# Composite Keys Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have this entity with four composite keys. Since Hibernate cannot generate entities with composite keys, I have to do it manually. That's the way I'm trying:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(ExamRequisitionPK.class)
@Table(name="ExamRequisitions")
@NamedQuery(name="ExamRequisition.findAll", query="SELECT er FROM  ExamRequisition er")
public class ExamRequisition implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)   
    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
    private int id;

    @Id
    @Column(nullable=false)
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="examId", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Exam exam;

    @Id 
    @Column(nullable=false)
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="patientId", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Patient patient;

    @Id
    @Column(nullable=false)
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="doctorId", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Doctor doctor;
```

With this entity mapped, what should I put in the IdClass (ExamREquisitionPK.class)? 
I'm newbie with this, it would be great if someone could help me.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, here are the rules:

> - A dependent entity might have multiple parent entities (i.e., a derived identifier might include multiple foreign keys).
> - If an entity class has multiple id attributes, then not only must it use an id class, but there must also be a corresponding attribute
>     of the same name in the id class as each of the id attributes in the
>     entity.
> - Id attributes in an entity might be of a simple type, or of an entity type that is the target of a many-to-one or one-to-one
>     relationship.
> - If an id attribute in an entity is of a simple type, then the type of    the matching attribute in the id class must be of the same
>     simple    type.
> - If an id attribute in an entity is a relationship, then the type of the matching attribute in the id class is of the same type as the
>     primary key type of the target entity in the relationship (whether the
>     primary key type is a simple type, an id class, or an embedded id
>     class).

I don't see the codes for the `Exam`, `Patient` and `Doctor` entity classes, but I'd like to make assumptions, by giving a sample code:

```
@Entity
public class Exam {

    @Id
    private String examId;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Patient {

    @Id
    private Long patientId;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Doctor {

    @Id
    private Integer doctorId;
    ...
}
```

Given the above code showing the type of each entity's primary key, here's what you should put in your `ExamREquisitionPK.class`:

```
public class ExamREquisitionPK {
    private int id; // matches the name of ExamRequisition 1st @Id attribute
    private String exam; // matches the name ExamRequisition 2nd @Id attribute but type should match with Exam's PK
    private Long patient; // matches the name ExamRequisition 3rd @Id attribute but type should match with Patient's PK
    private Integer doctor; // matches the name ExamRequisition 4th @Id attribute but type should match with Doctor's PK
}
```